# Save and close excel files in R

Tags: r

I tried to write R code to save and close all open excel files. I found the following, but this does not work

```
  library(RDCOMClient)
  xlApp <- RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  nBooks <- xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$Count()
  for (i in seq_len(nBooks)){
    xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$item(i)$Close(SaveChanges = TRUE)
  }
```

Even if some excel files are open, the nBooks is zero.
Any ideas how to fix this or do it differently?

I know I can kill all open instances just with

```
system("taskkill /F /IM Excel.exe")
```

But that doesn't allow for saving unsaved files.

Cheers

Renger

Comment: you can use `openxlsx` library, its way simpler

Comment: but it doesn't provide an option to close other excel file (e.g. not related to openxlsx) that  are open,